# JQuery show /hide div from drop down list change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three combobox that has each one should display and hide the respective div if selection is made.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $ ("select.cascade").on("change", function() {
  var which  = this.id, 
      div    = which + "d", 
      sel    = $(this).val();

  if (sel == '0') {
    $("#" + div).hide();
  } else {
    $("#" + div).show();
  }

  // Call form.submit here if need be
   });
});
</script>
```

Three dropdown list with div are given :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="c1" name="combobox" class="cascade">
    <option value="0">Select one...</option>
    <option id="WallyS" value="WallyS"> Walmart </option>
    <option id="AppliS" value="AppliS">Appliance</option>
    <option id="BBBS" value="BBBS">Beyond Presedential</option>
</select>
   <select id="c2" name="combobox1" class="cascade">
    <option value="0">Select one...</option>
    <option id="WallyS" value="WallyS"> Walmart </option>
    <option id="AppliS" value="AppliS">Appliance</option>
    <option id="BBBS" value="BBBS">Beyond Presedential</option>
</select>
 <select id="c3" name="combobox2" class="cascade">
    <option value="0">Select one...</option>
    <option id="WallyS" value="WallyS"> Walmart </option>
    <option id="AppliS" value="AppliS">Appliance</option>
    <option id="BBBS" value="BBBS">Beyond Presedential</option>
</select>

<div style="display:block">default</div>
<div id="c1d" class="WalLDP" style="display:none">content1 </div>
<div id="c2d" class="AppliDP" style="display:none">content2 </div>
<div id="c3d" class="BBBDP" style="display:none">content3</div>
```

it is running on http://jsfiddle.net/ ..but if i save it in notepad as php or html file and run through wamp server it just showing the comboboxes but not showing divs...please solve this problem

Comment: any errors in console??

Comment: no error ...combo boxes are shown but ..div are not displayed on changes made in comboxes

Answer (score 0):

Are you connected to the internet? I tried testing it on jsfiddle and it works correctly

Because the code below needs internet connection.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Here is the code I have on my laptop, just save it as a .html file. I hope this helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="c1" name="combobox" class="cascade">
    <option value="0">Select one...</option>
    <option id="WallyS" value="WallyS"> Walmart </option>
    <option id="AppliS" value="AppliS">Appliance</option>
    <option id="BBBS" value="BBBS">Beyond Presedential</option>
</select>
   <select id="c2" name="combobox1" class="cascade">
    <option value="0">Select one...</option>
    <option id="WallyS" value="WallyS"> Walmart </option>
    <option id="AppliS" value="AppliS">Appliance</option>
    <option id="BBBS" value="BBBS">Beyond Presedential</option>
</select>
 <select id="c3" name="combobox2" class="cascade">
    <option value="0">Select one...</option>
    <option id="WallyS" value="WallyS"> Walmart </option>
    <option id="AppliS" value="AppliS">Appliance</option>
    <option id="BBBS" value="BBBS">Beyond Presedential</option>
</select>

<div style="display:block">default</div>
<div id="c1d" class="WalLDP" style="display:none">content1 </div>
<div id="c2d" class="AppliDP" style="display:none">content2 </div>
<div id="c3d" class="BBBDP" style="display:none">content3</div>



</body>


<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $ ("select.cascade").on("change", function() {
  var which  = this.id, 
      div    = which + "d", 
      sel    = $(this).val();

  if (sel == '0') {
    $("#" + div).hide();
  } else {
    $("#" + div).show();
  }

  // Call form.submit here if need be
   });
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: still same situation combo box shows no div on change in selection..yes internet is connected on mac

Comment: I have copied your code on my laptop as a .html file, it works correctly showing content1 when clicking Walmart and so on. Turned off my wifi and it does not work anymore. How about you create the jquery file instead pointing at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: or press command + r key on your mac to clear javascript cache on your chrome browser :)

Comment: still not working...with local path      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jsfile.js"></script>

Comment: can you add an alert("test"); inside $(document).ready(), just to check if js is okay. Also, clear js cache, by using **command + r** for chrome on mac

Comment: alert("test"); is not shown on page refresh and then changing combo box value

Comment: There are no errors chrome console log? and also you might have  other js code that messes the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

*you have to correct the url please*

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
or
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### see in action <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uubc0mq4/)</kbd>